# Python list slicing not working correctly

Tags: python

I have recently started learning python. After learning list slicing, I thought of trying it out. But when I am using **-1**, it's returning an empty list

```
numbers = [2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 0, 1]
# Slicing a list
print(numbers[1:5:-1])
```

gives,
**[ ]**
This video tells that -1 works:
[Here](https://youtu.be/neTsPE9XFsQ)

Can you guys tell me why is it like that?

Comment: if the direction is backwards, the starting index should be larger than ending index, for example `numbers[5:1:-1]` outputs `[0, 6, 5, 9]`, note that the ending index 1 is not inclusive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify indices so that the start comes after the end, you always get an empty slice:

```
>>> numbers = [2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 0, 1]
>>> numbers[5:1]
[]
```

Putting `-1` on the end reverses the slice, so you need to reverse the indices as well if you're doing it as part of the same slice:

```
>>> numbers[::-1]
[1, 0, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2]
>>> numbers[5:1:-1]
[0, 6, 5, 9]
```

This is the same as if you took the reverse slice on its own and then sliced it with `[1:5]` afterward:

```
>>> numbers[::-1][1:5]
[0, 6, 5, 9]
```